# Sencha Touch 2 - How to check if an item exists in the ViewPort

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

What I want to do, basically, is to dynamically load views into the ViewPort when needed. In order to do that, I need to find out if the view was already added to the ViewPort so it doesn't get added multiple times. However looking at sencha touch documentation I was not able to find a proper way to check if an item exists inside the ViewPort.

So in summary

1 - Check if the ViewPort contains the view I want to set as active. Something like this:

```
if(!Ext.Viewport.items.contains('myviewtoactivate'))
    Ext.Viewport.add([{ xtype: 'myviewtoactivate' }]);
```

2 - Then I would set this view as active (this part I already know how to do).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this inside your controller:

```
    var main = this.getMain(),
        myview = main.down('myview');

    if(!myview){
        myview = main.add({
            xtype: 'myview'
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know. But for what I understood, down() receives a selector, and I'm not sure if a selector can be a xtype.

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot man! Good to know I can use the xtype as selector.